# TClientSocket : what is the difference between SendBuffer and SendStream?

Tags: delphi, sockets

Hello all i have a mission to implement a protocol to communicate with a server.I have a dilemma and maybe someone skilled enough can enlighten me.When i connect to the server i must send an array of bytes the problem is when when i use this i get disconnected imediatley from the server:

```
  var 
   buffer : array [0..200] of byte;
   begin
   ClientSocket1.Socket.SendBuf(buffer[0],length(buffer));
   end;
```

but when i use this it works fine:

```
   var 
   buffer : array [0..200] of byte;
   mem_ste : TMemoryStream;
   begin
   mem_ste := TMemoryStream.Create;
   mem_ste.Write(buffer[0],length(buffer));
   ClientSocket1.Socket.SendStream(mem_ste);
   end;
```

Is there any logical reason please tell me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first code, you're sending 201 bytes of uninitialized garbage, so it's no wonder the server kicks you off.

In the second code, you're writing 201 bytes of uninitialized garbage into a stream, but then sending *nothing* through the socket because the current `Position` property of the stream is still at the end of the stream — there's nothing to send. `SendStream` starts at the current stream position and reads until it reaches the end.

Comment: this is only theory i didn't paste here the actual code because is very large but thanks for the explanation about the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a possibility for exception in `SendBuf`? Delphi Help have following:

> If an error occurs while writing to the connection, SendBuf terminates
>   the connection and raises an ESocketError exception.

Another idea - is you socket in blocking mode? If not, `SendBuf` might fail, if called not in `onWrite` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your use of `SendBuf()` (assuming the data itself is accurate), so the problem has to be related to something else.  Are you getting an `OnError` event triggered?

Comment: nope i just get disconnected from the server with an error code...but if i send it as a stream no error pops up